# sql query disregarding all rows that have all null columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Server query that needs to count the number of rows returned, but I need to disregard rows where all the column values are NULL. Some rows have NULL values for some of the columns, but that is ok. I just need to filter out the ones that have ALL NULL values.

Right now I am returning all rows and using a SqlDataReader iterating the returned rows and counting the ones I need. I would like to move this into the query itself if possible.

Thanks!

EDIT: What I am trying to do is similar to this, but I am apparently having a hard time making the VS SQL editor recognize what I'm doing:

```
SELECT COUNT(sd.[ID]) 
FROM [Some Data] sd 
WHERE sd.[Data Name] = 'something' AND ((sd.q1 IS NOT NULL) OR (sd.q2 IS NOT NULL))
```

etc..

Comment: Your T-SQL code will not run. You don't specify OR with '||'. But, even so, you need an AND and not an OR.

Comment: oops, I knew that. Either way, I do not want an AND. I need the results to follow that expression. I just don't know how to "say it" in SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select count(id)
from [Some Data]
where not (Column1 is null and Column2 is null and Column3 is null ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

Select Count(*) From MyTable
Where Column1 IS NOT NULL And Column2 IS NOT NULL And Column3 IS NOT NULL ...

Comment: This will not work, as there are some columns that are NULL and I want to count those, just not the ones that are *not* all NULL. See my recent Edit as to an example.

Answer (score 1):

You already selected an answer, but this is the most correct it should be the fastest because the SQL Engine can optimize it and "short circuit" it.

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM [Some Data]
WHERE NOT (COALESCE(Column1,Column2,Column3...) is null)
```

Comment: I'm sure SQL Server is smart enough to short-circuit the code in my answer too - but yours is more succinct. Wish I'd thought of it :P

Comment: I'm not sure, I've seen a number of cases where SQL will evaluate all elements in and statements.  This is especially a pain when you have something like `isnumber(col) and cast(col as int) = 1`